# Wu experiment beta decay

Tags: experimental-physics, parity, weak-interaction, cp-violation

maybe it's a stupid question. But in Wu experiment she showed that parity in not conserved in beta decay. So how to say on general that this is true for any weak force interaction?

Answer (score 1):

> So how to say on general that this is true for any weak force interaction?

do you mean to ask: "why is this assumed for all weak interactions"?

Weak interactions were classified by their "weakness". Lifetimes were long and interactions much more weak than electromagnetic or strong. The suggestion was made by Lee and Yang that as a class parity violation was a part of the [weak interactions led to the experiment](https://books.google.gr/books?id=A15OvAvA7HAC&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=observation%20of%20parity%20violation%20%20in%20muon%20decay&source=bl&ots=Zc-Y1AFeHY&sig=2JGhT5I0bOkXBEUouToKM8HKoaU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBWoVChMIjeGn0cScyQIVTLwaCh1uUgmG#v=onepage&q=observation%20of%20parity%20violation%20%20in%20muon%20decay&f=false) you describe due to the [tau theta puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon#Parity_violation):

[image]

So the answer is that the theory developed for weak interactions fitted all weak decay and interaction data.